# How Iterator works in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I am learning container in C++ and trying to insert and print element of list with the help of iterator. I am getting a different output then my expectations.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<deque>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> ilist(10);
    cout<<ilist.size()<<endl;
    list<int>::iterator litr = ilist.begin();
    int i =0;
    for(litr = ilist.begin();litr != ilist.end();litr++,i++)
    {
        cout<<"i:"<<i<<" ";
        //ilist.push_back(i);
        *litr=i;
        litr++;
    }
    litr = ilist.begin();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<ilist.size();
    while(litr != ilist.end())
    {
        i=*litr;

        cout<<i<<endl;
        litr++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output :
10
i:0 i:1 i:2 i:3 i:4
100
0
1
0
2
0
3
0
4
0

why size changed after Inserting element and why elements are not properly inserted ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are increasing iteration two times

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop, you are incrementing the iterator twice per iteration (once in the `for` statement and once more at the bottom of the loop).

This causes the iterator to skip every other element.

The size of the list remains unchanged: the `100` is `10` immediately followed by `0`. The `10` is the size of the list and the `0` is the first element of the list. Print a space or a newline after printing out the size and you'll see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop

```
for(litr = ilist.begin();litr != ilist.end();litr++,i++)
{
    cout<<"i:"<<i<<" ";
    //ilist.push_back(i);
    *litr=i;
    litr++;
}
```

you are increasing iterator litr twice: in the control statement and within the body of the loop.
It could be written simpler

```
list<int>::iterator litr;
int i = 0;

for ( litr = ilist.begin(); litr != ilist.end(); litr++, i++ )
{
    cout<<"i:"<<i<<" ";
    *litr = i;
}
```

Or

```
list<int>::iterator litr;
int i = 0;

for ( litr = ilist.begin(); litr != ilist.end(); litr++ )
{
    cout<<"i:"<<i<<" ";
    *litr = i++;
}
```

As for the output then that it would be more clear you need to insert `std::endl` after printing the size the second time. For example

```
cout<<ilist.size() << endl;
//                 ^^^^^^^
while(litr != ilist.end())
{
    i=*litr;

    cout<<i<<endl;
    litr++;
}
```

Then the output will look like

```
10 
i:0 i:1 i:2 i:3 i:4 
10
0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0
```

Take into account that there are several standard algorithms declared in header `<algorithm>` that can do the same task. For example you could use algorithm `std::generate`.

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int i = 0;
std::generate( ilist.begin(), ilist.end(), [&] { return i++; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Size did not change. Before second loop you display size of the list and then it's contents without any separator. Since the first element in the list is equal to 0 it looks as if the list grew to the length of 100.
Also, like NPE has mentioned, in the first loop you increment the iterator twice.